# Pass array to Laravel partial from View

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to pass an array from view to partial. Currently it's possible to do it for a single variable this way:

```
@include('partials.datatable' , ['var' => 'value'])
```

But I want `var` to be an array like this:

```
@include('partials.datatable' , ['var' => ['value1', 'value2']])
```

So I should use it in partial as:

```
{{ $var[0] }}
```

Is it possible to do such thing?

Comment: If you're including views in other views whatever you pass in to the parent will be available in the child. So you could very well pass in your array when the view is created and it will be available to the included view.

Comment: please make an example..

Comment: partial views will inherit the variables made available to the parent view. In your case, if $var is available in the current view, you can access it in the partial view, no need to pass it. But if not, you way of passing the variables  should have no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how it works. 
I was looking for some examples, landed here.
e.g Parent:

```
@include('layouts.companies', ['popular_agencies' => $popular_agencies])
```

Child:

```
@foreach ($popular_agencies as $popular)
     //Do something here..
@endforeach
```